# probability of rolling at least $n$ on $k$ 6-sided dice

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, dice

Is there a simple form for the probability of rolling at least $n$ on $k$ 6-sided dice?  Of course you can do it by recursion (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36677/whats-the-probability-of-rolling-at-least-k-on-n-dice-with-s-1-ldots-s-n)).  But is there a way to do it with just a few binomial coefficients, without the recursion?

Comment: If you're willing to sacrifice accuracy, you can use the normal approximation, if $k$ is large. There isn't much alternative apart form doing the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to know is [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html).

The formula for a homogeneous and fair dice from 1 to *D* values is this

$$P(S,n,D)=\frac{1}{D^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(S-n)/D\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{S-Dk-1}{n-1}$$

where *S* is the sum that you want, *n* is the number of dice you roll and *D* is the number of sides of the dice (D6, D8, etc.)

To know the sum of *at least S* just need to sum what you want over *S*.

---

A better way: in the book of *generatingfunctionology* there is an exercise in the chapter one asking just this but the answer is nicer.

We set $P(x):=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac1m x^k=x(1-x^m)/m(1-x)$, then $P$ is the generating function of the probabilities of a fair dice of $m$ sides and $[x^\ell]P(x)^n/(1-x)$ is the probability to get at lest a sum of $\ell$ throwing $n$ times the dice. The closed form is
$$
\begin{align}[x^\ell]P(x)^n/(1-x)&=m^{-n}[x^\ell]x^n(1-x^m)^n(1-x)^{-n-1}\\
&=m^{-n}[x^\ell]\sum_{j,k\ge 0}\binom{n}{k}\binom{-n-1}{j}(-1)^{k+j}x^{km+j+n}\\
&=m^{-n}[x^\ell]\sum_{j,k\ge 0}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+j}{j}(-1)^kx^{km+j+n},\quad km+j+n=\ell\\
&=m^{-n}\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n}{k}\binom{\ell-km}{n}(-1)^k\end{align}
$$