# Average value from summed uniform rolls with threshold

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, dice, stopping-times

Suppose you roll an 6-sided dice and sum the values until a threshold is reached. When that threshold is reached any overflowing amount is discarded. What is the average dice roll value, depending on that threshold value?

For a threshold of **1**, the average roll would also be **1**, since any dice roll is capped to a value of **1**.

For an infinitely large threshold, the average roll would be **3.5**.

What would be the formula to calculate the average value of a roll for a **N**-sided dice and a **T** threshold?

Simulations I made using python :

[image: Average roll value for a 6-sided dice and varying threshold]

[image: Average roll value for a 30-sided dice and varying threshold]

Comment: Why this downvote for this clear question displaying work (simulation) ???

Comment: Could you give more details please? e.g. for 6 sides and $T=2$, if we get any value between 2 and 6 it is counted as a 2? So with probability 5/6 it is 2, and probability 1/6 it is 1, so the expected dice roll value is 2*5/6+1*1/6=11/6? But in your simulation it looks like we are under 1.5 for $T=2$, yet $11/6\simeq1.83$. Is there something I didn't understand?

Comment: @Will Yes, any value between 2 and 6 will be counted as 2, but only if it happens on the first roll. If the first roll is a 1, the 2nd roll will always be counted as 1. This means that the average roll is worth **1.714**, not **1.83**. I've edited the graphs to make it easier to see the average values for each threshold.

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch for an analytical solution:** you are asking for the expectation related to something that in probability theory is named an *stopping time* related to an stochastic process, i.e., related to a sequence of random variables.

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, where each $X_k$ represents a dice, and set $T:=\min\{n: S_n\geqslant t\}$ for some fixed $t>0$ (the threshold), where $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. Then $T$ is the number of throws where you reach the threshold.

Now suppose that $T=n$, that is, we have that $S_n\geqslant t$ but $S_{n-1}<t$. This means that $S_n=t+k$ for some $k\in\{0,\ldots ,s-1\}$, being $s$ the number of sides of the dice. In this case you will have that the mean value of the dice will be just $t/n$, as we discard the value of $k$ every time, therefore we want to compute
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac{t}{n}P(T=n)=t \sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac1{n}P(T=n)=t\, \mathrm{E}[1/T]\tag1
$$
Now we can use the following result to approach $\mathrm{E}[1/T]$: suppose that $g:[a,\infty )\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and monotonic, and that $\operatorname{supp}(X)\subset [a,\infty )$, then
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{E}[g(X)]&=\int_{[a,\infty )}g(t)P_X(dt)\\
&=\int_{[a,\infty )}(g(t)+g(a)-g(a))P_X(dt)\\
&=\int_{[a,\infty )}\left(\left(\int_{[a,t]}g'(s)\,d s\right)+g(a)\right)P_X(dt)\\
&=g(a)+\int_{\{(s,t):a\leqslant s\leqslant t\}}g'(s)\,d s \otimes P_X(dt)\\
&=g(a)+\int_{[a,\infty )}g'(s)P(X\geqslant  s)\,d s\tag2
\end{align*}
$$
where we used Tonelli's theorem in the last two equalities. In our case first note that
$$
\{T\geqslant r\}=\{T\geqslant \lceil r \rceil \}=\{S_{\lceil r \rceil -1}<t\}=\{S_{\lceil r\rceil-1 }\leqslant \lceil t-1\rceil \}\tag3
$$
Then using (2) and (3) we reach the identity
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{E}[1/T]&=1-\int_{[1,\infty )}\frac1{r^2}P(T\geqslant r)\,d r\\
&=1-\int_{[1,\infty )}\frac1{r^2}P(T\geqslant \lceil r \rceil  )\,d r\\
&=1-\int_{[1,\infty )}\frac1{r^2}P(S_{\lceil r \rceil -1 }\leqslant \lceil t-1 \rceil )\,d r\\
&=1-\sum_{n\geqslant 1}P(S_n\leqslant \lceil t-1 \rceil )\int_{[0,1]}\frac1{(n+s)^2}\,d s\\
&=1-\sum_{n\geqslant 1}P(S_n\leqslant \lceil t -1\rceil )\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\\
&=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\lceil t -1\rceil }P(S_n\leqslant \lceil t-1 \rceil )\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\tag4
\end{align*}
$$
(Note that (4) can be derived more straightforwardly from (1) using summation by parts.)

I'm not sure if this is the more simple or useful approach to the problem, besides a Montecarlo simulation. Anyway the distribution of each $S_n$ for large $n$ can be approximated well by a normal distribution, so we can get some bounds for $\mathrm{E}[1/T]$. For an explicit computation of the cumulative distribution of each $S_n$ take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/928448/173262).

Comment: looks to me that we would be rather interested (with your notation and not OP's) in $t\mathbb E[1/T]$.

Comment: @Will you are right, I misread the problem. I've rewritten my answer almost completely.